# Using JavaCV to Analyze Images on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, robotics

I'm a little stuck here.  I'd like to use the JavaCV library to capture a frame from a camera and store the pixels in a matrix.  Unfortunately, all the tutorials that I can find only demonstrate how to do this on an ordinary computer, and since this is for an android application I can't use the necessary AWT library that the tutorials point to.  Could somebody please either point me to a tutorial or explain a way that allows me to accomplish this on Android?
I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: It should be possible to capture with OpenCV and FFmpeg even on Android now. Please give it a try with the snapshots since it's not released yet: http://bytedeco.org/builds/